# Backbone js capitalise first letter of words

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am picking results from the views and showing them in the templates like this,

```
 <%  users.each(function(user){ %>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="center">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                                            <span class="lbl"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <%= user.get("first_name") %>
<% }); %>
```

How can i have this `<%= user.get("first_name") %>` to be capitalised just like in rails with the `titleize` method in rails.

Answer (score 2):

Is CSS an options? f.e.

```
td {
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<%= user.get("first_name").titleize %>
```